# How do I know what type of RAM I have?

Tags: upgrade, memory

I've got an old computer from a friend of mine that does not use it anymore i order to use it like a test server. Now, I'd like to upgrade it, by adding to it some RAM.

Wondering about how to know what kind of RAM should I add: SDR or DDR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Head on over to crucial.com's website and run their [**Crucial System Scanner**](http://www.crucial.com/systemscanner/index.aspx) tool.

This will tell you exactly what memory your computer uses, how many slots there are and exactly what memory will be compatible.

They even offer a money back guarantee if you purchase through their website using their scanner and it turns out to be incompatible.

Comment: # Maximum Memory Capacity:  2048MB
# Currently Installed Memory:  1GB
# Available Memory Slots:  1
# Total Memory Slots:  2
*** # Dual Channel Support:   No ***
could I use any type of DDR - DDR II, III or a specific one?

Comment: @Serhio you will need DDR2 667 MHz RAM, preferably with the same timings as the one reported by CPU-z.

Answer (score 7):

You might want to install [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/cpuz.php) from CPUID.

Here's what you see (with mine, that is):

[image]

Comment: *** # Dual Channel Support:   No ***
http://www.crucial.com/systemscanner/viewscanbyid.aspx?id=2BA0E1E131D926C3

could I use any type of DDR - DDR II, III or a specific one?