# How do I know frequency of RAM

Tags: memory, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I know what type of RAM I have?](https://superuser.com/questions/114572/how-do-i-know-what-type-of-ram-i-have)
>   [How to know which RAM I can/should buy for my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/289941/how-to-know-which-ram-i-can-should-buy-for-my-pc)

I want to upgrade ram of my laptop. I have Lenovo Y510 with intel dual core T2330 1.6 ghz processor 533mhz FSB. For better performance I want to upgrade ram. I opened up my laptop and saw ram but frequency was not mentioned there. I have attached here two images one of boot screen of my machine and second is of ram.
Looking at both can you please tell me what is the frequency or ram I should go with for upgradation.
I think ram is of 667mhz but not sure.

[image]

[image]

Comment: no attachment...

Answer (score 0):

In the second screen shot, it shows you the ram spec.

```
DDR2-533/CL4
```

The 533 in the above line denotes ram speed (frequency), the CL4 is the CAS Latency Settings (the lower the number, the faster the ram can respond).

Comment: so you mean frequency of ram is 533 mhz? and I should buy ddr2 ram of 533 mhz?

Comment: Precisely.. looking at the ram stick, i imagine you will want to look for PC2-5300S 533MHZ sticks.. There are programs online which you can install to be absolutely sure of the ram spec you have. CPU-Z (www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) is a great tool and very easy to use and will tell you everything you need to know.. Its better to learn to use a tool like this and make sure yourself, for peace of mind if nothing else.