# How to find out what is the "best" RAM for me?

Tags: windows-7, memory

I have an Asus p7p55 lx mobo. Tomorrow I'm finally going to install Win7 and decided to upgrade my RMA to 16GB which is the max. the mobo supports. What I could get from the website is that the RAM is this

> 4 x DIMM, Max. 16GB, DDR3 2200(O.C.)/1600/1333/1066 Hz Non-ECC,
>   Un-buffered Memory Dual Channel Memory Architecture Supports Intel®
>   Extreme Memory Profile (XMP)
>   * Hyper DIMM support is subject to the physical characteristics of individual CPUs. 
>   * Refer to www.asus.com or user manual for the Memory QVL (Qualified Vendors Lists).

So this means I can have up to 16GB which is fine I think. Is this using 4 memory sticks? Would that be better than 2 (4 x 4GB vs. 2 x 8GB)? What about the memory freq.? 1600MHz seems to be a standard. What is the 2200MHz when overclocked? How do I know the timing properties that should be used or which one to use?

Thanks!

Comment: you want to know what memory is compatible? Just use the Crucial Memory Tool, there are a lot of posts in Super User on the tool. http://superuser.com/questions/114572/how-do-i-know-what-type-of-ram-i-have/114575#114575  Overclocking is another matter...

Comment: I would like to know if I should get 2 sticks of 8GB over 4 sticks of 4GB and what other properties matter if any?

Comment: use the Crucial Tool, it will tell you exactly what you have and what you can add. Your mobo only has 2 slots, so if you want 16gb you will need 2 8gb sticks.

Comment: Thanks for the link, however it will only offer RAM by Crucial. I don't have that brand in stored around here. The mobo does have 4 slots BTW, which configuration is better?

Comment: Why would you install windows 7? I recommend installing windows 8.1 it requires less system resources. If you have less than 4gb, install the 32 bit version of the OS, if you have 4 gb or more, install the 64 bit version of the OS.